# Logback / Weblogic How to set different log level?

Tags: logback

I am using Weblogic 10.3.6 and I am not able to control different log level for 2 different appenders (com.my & root)
With the given logback.xml I am expecting a TRACE level only for the file appender and nothing under weblogic terminal. Issue is I get the same output on both.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- For assistance related to logback-translator or configuration  -->
<!-- files in general, please contact the logback user mailing list -->
<!-- at http://www.qos.ch/mailman/listinfo/logback-user             -->
<!--                                                                -->
<!-- For professional support please see                            -->
<!--    http://www.qos.ch/shop/products/professionalSupport         -->
<!--                                                                -->
<configuration>
    <contextName>myContx</contextName>
    <jmxConfigurator />
    <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <!--See also http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender-->
        <File>/var/log/a.log</File>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <maxIndex>1</maxIndex>
            <FileNamePattern>/var/log/a.log.%i</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>1MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>
    <appender name="out"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %class - %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <logger name="com.my" level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </logger>
    <root level="off">
        <appender-ref ref="out" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say that setting additivity flag would help you:

```xml
<logger name="com.my" level="trace" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</logger>
```

See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#overrridingCumulativity.